# Saving many values in a MongoDB Collection & node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an API which I call three times with three different parameters.

`https://api.developer.com/${param1} // param2, and param3`

This api returns 30,000+ results each time. (total of around 100,000).

I want to store this data in a single `collection`. Meaning, I want 100,000+ `documents` in one collection.

I have a small script that extends the npm `request` module, which looks like this:

````
```
let _request = (urls, cb) => {
    let results = {}, i = urls.length, c = 0;
    handler = (err, response, body) => {
        let url = response.request.uri.href;
        results[url] = { err, response, body };

        if (++c === urls.length) {
            cb(results);
        }
    };
    while (i--) {
        request(urls[i], handler);
    }
};

```
````

But let's exclude that for now. The function which I use to GET a single endpoint, and update the Database after is this:

```
function update() {
  request(url, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      let json = {};

      try {
        json = JSON.parse(body);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }

      _.forOwn(json, (price, market_hash_name) => {
        Price.update(
          { market_hash_name },
          {
            $set: { price }
          },
          { upsert: true },
          err => {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
  });
}
```

The raw data returned looks like this:

```
{
  market_hash_name: price,
  market_hash_name: price.. etc
}
```

**The problem:**

Even though, `Object.keys(data).length === 30000`, my MongoDB collection only writes down ~10,000 documents, and the other ~20000 vanish into thin air.
I've checked a thousand times, with Postman, Browser and even logging the data.keys in the console, and I am sure there are 30k + key:value pairs.

Is it something wrong with my code? Is it bad practice to call Price.update for every key:value pair in the json (probably). But I'm stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: First I have to ask why 30,000+ documents at a time? Could you do this same operation with pagination?

Comment: @jmb.mage I am getting 30,000 results from the JSON. I need them all in the Collection. They are basically prices of ALL items on the market, and not only do I have to get them once, but I have to update them every 30 minutes (the API that I'm getting them from is updated at the same interval). I am pretty new at NoSQL, but how do you suggest doing this?

Comment: Without knowing too much about your project the "~20000 vanish" part of the question is most alarming.  Are you familiar with the concept of pagination?  It may require some AJAX chaining to update the list in batches.

Comment: I am researching it now. Thanks for the pointer!